# Implicit conversion not assignable to interface

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have a class with an implicit conversion from `string` defined as:

```
class TestClass : ITestInterface
{
    public static implicit operator TestClass(string value)
    {
        return new TestClass(value);
    }

    public TestClass(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

It implements a marker interface:

```
public interface ITestInterface { }
```

I have a method of another class defined as:

```
public void DoSomething(ITestInterface thing) { }
```

I'm getting an error trying to call that method:

```
public void Test()
{
    TestClass a = "This works fine.";
    DoSomething("Why doesn't this work?");
}
```

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'Tests.ITestInterface'

All code is greatly simplified; my actually requirements are far more complex, but this seems to be the core of what is blocking the pattern I'd like to implement.

What is preventing this from working? (Something in the C# spec?)
Are there any changes I can make to my code to allow this type of casting to work?

Comment: Whilst there is an implicit conversion from string to your class, there is none from string to your interface. You´d have to explicitley cast the string to your class. However it seems quite odd to me to even try to think about **casting** a string to your class. By doing so you imply that **every** string can safely be converted to your class, what I doubt is what you want.

Comment: Whats wrong with `TestClass a = new TestClass("This works fine.");` seems to be a lot more user friendly to me

Comment: @HimBromBeere In this particular case, every `string` is a valid conversion.  In my full code, this is part of the representation of a "document". A document can be created through a constructor that looks like `Document(params IPart[] parts)`.  I am trying to make it easy to include blocks of `string` content mixed in with other types of content.

Comment: But even on a document I suppose you have some fix structure for the data within that document. I doubt "my arbitrary string" is a valid representation of your class, is it?

Comment: The class is specifically designed as a wrapper around arbitrary string content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're omitting the third option that explains the issue:

```
//1
TestClass a = "This works fine.";

//2
ITestInterface i = "This doesn't work either!";

//3
DoSomething("Why doesn't this work?");
```

In **(1)**, you've declared `TestClass a`. This means that the compiler knows that when you use a different type (string, in this case), that it should try to convert said value to `TestClass`.

In **(2)**, you've declared `ITestInterface i`. This means that the compiler knows that when you use a different type (string, in this case), that it should try to convert said value to `ITestInterface`.

That is the source of the problem. There is no conversion defined between `string` and `ITestInterface`.

What you're currently thinking is:

> *Well, **I** know that I want this to be converted to a `TestClass`. Why doesn't the compiler figure out what I want it to do?*

The short answer to that is that **the compiler refuses to guess**.

What you want to happen would lead to impossible situations. For example, what would happen if there was a second class which also implements `ITestInterface`?

```
class SecondTestClass: ITestInterface
{
    public static implicit operator SecondTestClass(string url)
    {
        return new SecondTestClass(url);
    }

    public SecondTestClass(string url)
    {
        Value = GetValueFromTheInternet(url);
    }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Let's re-evaluate your code:

```
//1
TestClass a = "This works fine.";
```

This works. There is a conversion from `string` to `TestClass`.

```
//2
SecondTestClass b = "This works fine.";
```

This works. There is a conversion from `string` to `SecondTestClass`.

```
//3
ITestInterface i = "This still doesn't work!";

//4
DoSomething("This doesn't work for the same reason as //3");
```

This doesn't work. The compiler does not have any known conversion from `string` to `ITestInterface`.

The compiler is unable to figure out if you want this to be converted to a `TestClass` and then assigned to `i`, or if you want this to be converted to a `SecondTestClass` and then assigned to `i`.

And, as I said before, the compiler refuses to guess.

Also, just for clarity, this would work:

```
TestClass a = "This works fine.";

ITestInterface i1 = a;
DoSomething(a);
DoSomething(i1);

SecondTestClass b = "This works fine.";

ITestInterface i2 = b;
DoSomething(b);
DoSomething(i2);
```

All of these assignations work.

The crux of your problem is that the compiler wants you to **explicitly** state which type you want the string to be converted to. In your own example, you were already explicitly asking for a `TestClass`. Notice that this would not have worked if you had used `var`, as the compiler would not be able to figure it out in that case either.

Comment: Thank you, the situation with multiple potential classes implementing implicit conversions is the part I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty clear from the compiler-error, isn´t it? `DoSomething` expects an instance of `ITestInterface`, which `string` does not implement. The fact that there is an implicit conversion from string to your class doesn´t make this conversion also applicable for any other class implementing the interface.

Imagine there was another class implementing the interface:

```
class AnotherTestClass : ITestInterface { }
```

how would the `DoSomething`-call now be resolved? To which class should the conversion apply? To an instance of `TestClass` or to `AnotherTestClass`? In particular if `AnotherClass` also has an implicit cast-operator defined. That´s why this does not work.

Or consider the other way round: when you have only the interface but no class at all that implements it (which is pretty common when you design an API), there is no conversion at all. Your design introduces some static binding from an interface to a concrete implementation of it, which is a bad thing. In fact that makes your `DoSomething`-method only work for instances of type `TestClass`, which contradicts the use of an interface as parameter. So however uses your API can use only ever provide an instance of `TestClass` to your method.

Apart from this I doubt a cast is a good thing here. By having an implicit concversion you imply that **every** string can safely be converted to your class without losing any information. E.g. is an URI a valid representation of your class? Or even your provided `"Why doesn't this work?"`?

On the other side a constructor that expects a string is far more precise and makes it clear:

```
var m = new TestClass(myString);
```

From my experience there are only some very few cases where you really need an implicit cast. What you do far more often is to create some instance based upon some input and **append** some more data to that instance. In your example that means that a `TestClass` consists of some string-information, but may also have some more data.

Comment: Thank you, the situation with multiple potential classes implementing implicit conversions is the part I was missing.

Comment: @BradleyUffner by your design you have some static binding from an interface to a concrete class. Usually the use of an interface is to be *independant* from any implementation.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic the same pattern used by the constructor of `XElement` that allows the developer to build a document tree out of nodes, attributes, and string content.  I just wanted to include a bit more type safety (`XElement` uses an `object` array).

Comment: While I did question if a cast is necessary, I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's provably bad to use either. Note that "converts to an object" and "is valid" are two very different traits. I can do `new Person() { Name = "http://google.com" };` too. The possibility to make mistakes is not a valid justification (by itself) that I should not make this property publically settable. (Taken to an extreme, that would lead you down a path of not leaking primitive types to your consumer and instead forcing them to use your data class).

Comment: [..] The choice between a string conversion and a constructor with a single string parameter is one of **style**. Implicit conversion tends to lower maintainability by lowering readability. However, if the current codebase has a tremendous amount of string-to-object casting going on, then it might be beneficial to simplify that code to an implicit conversion when that conversion is innately understandable from the developer's point of view. For example, (taken from another post today): `Airport destination = "LAX";`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DoSomething(ITestInterface thing) { }
```

Because the parameter is an interface and you want to call `static implicit operator TestClass(string value)` but it is impossible. The interface in C# can not have `static` method.
You can pass a class `TestClass` as a parameter only

```
public static void DoSomething(TestClass thing) { Console.WriteLine(thing.Value); }
```

Comment: The issue here is not caused by the static nature of the operator class, nor the inability for interfaces to have static members. OP's issue would also occur if he were using a base and derived class instead of an interface and an implementing class, at which point your argument no longer applies. (Though I would expect the source of OP's issue to be more obvious if he had used a base class).